# Populate Form from stored session

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a razor form:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.SystolicBT, new{@class="RiskScoreTextBox"})
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.PersonWeight, new{@class="RiskScoreTextBox"})
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.PersonWeight, new{@class="RiskScoreTextBox"})
```

Then i have this method that retrives the object and stores it in a session.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePrototype(DementiaPrototypeModel Prototype)
    {
        Session["DemensPrototype"] = Prototype;

        return RedirectToAction("RiskScore");
    }
```

And after that i am send to this method:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RiskScore()
    {
        var prototype = Session["DemensPrototype"];
        return View();
    }
```

Here i can se the object if i hoover over prototype, but now i have a similar form that i want to populate with the  object info ive stored. How do i do that?

Comment: Can't you simply cast the object to a DementialPrototypeModel object and pass that to your view as the model, or am I misinterpreting your intention?

Comment: Maybe thats is want i want to do! I want to open the object and populate my form again. The object is created from get, set methods so i could populate those and then get the values but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var prototype = Session["DemensPrototype"] as DementialPrototypeModel;
return View(prototype);
```

or, this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePrototype(DementiaPrototypeModel Prototype)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RiskScore", Prototype);
    }

[HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RiskScore(DementiaPrototypeModel prototype)
    {
        return View(prototype);
    }
```

Just make sure your view is expecting a DementialPrototypeModel object as its model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works so far :) but what do you mean by expecting?

Comment: The view should be strongly typed to a DementialPrototypeModel object if you're passing that object as the model. Glad I could help.